# Error:Android Dex: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/sinovoice/hcicloudsdk/recorder/ASRCommonRecorder;

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 1.0. I tried to immigrate my projects from eclipse to android which is not gradle-built, but it's keeping coming out this error. I did some search about this kind of problem and found there are two dependency library projects using the same support-v4.jar, and I've already deleted one of them, but still got this error, here is the error log. Anybody can help?

> Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0]
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/sinovoice/hcicloudsdk/recorder/ASRCommonRecorder; Error:Android
>   Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189) Error:Android
>   Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246) Error:Android
>   Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) Error:Android Dex:
>   [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
>   Error:Android Dex: [duoduo_passenger_4.0] at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar errror by adding following code to my build.gradle file inside the android block.

```
 dexOptions {
     preDexLibraries = false
 }
```